# GameObject.name vs new GameObject(name)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject

Is there a difference *performance-wise* between using

**Example 1**

```
var myObject = new GameObject();
myObject.name = "myObjectName";
```

And

**Example 2**

```
var myObject = new GameObject("myObjectName");
```

Some articles like [this](https://divillysausages.com/2016/01/21/performance-tips-for-unity-2d-mobile/) suggest avoiding **Example 1** because native code is called, hurting performance.

Out of curiosity, I checked [the documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject-ctor.html) of the `GameObject` class and there are no remarks indicating how any of the constructors might affect performance.

My current theory is that **Example 2** is similar to [instantiating an object and immediately specifying a parent](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) as that is supposedly better than instantiating an object and specifying the parent later.

Comment: Might be worth just testing each and seeing if one performs better than the other

Comment: I looked unity source code , example1 and example2 also called native code. so maybe you can write somthing test to check it?

Comment: First example requires more property accesses so probably the second is faster. But honestly unless you do this for 10.000 objects I don't think it would matter really, compared to the time needed for the instantiating itself the impact of setting the name should be quite small.

Comment: Out of sheer curiosity, how many times are you doing this that you are so concerned about the performance?

Comment: Maybe 100 or so calls at a time. It helped identify what objects were in the scene, but that is only useful in the editor and i found I wasn't really relying on this too much anyway. A lot of other things happen at the same time so the more overhead i can eliminate the better. I am also testing on a low end mobile device!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have answered my own question.

The second example runs 0.41 milliseconds faster, but allocates the same amount of memory as the first.

[image]

Comment: Can you call 100 times ? because time is too limit.